# Splitting up string contents of 2 or more columns in python dataframe and appending to new rows in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a problem where there are multiple rows in a csv file that I have converted to a pandas data frame. However there are some rows where the columns 'name' and 'business' have multiple names and businesses that need to be split up and placed into individual rows while keeping the data from the other columns the same for each row that is split.

Here is the example data:

input:

| software | name | business |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | Andrew Johnson, Steve Martin | Outsourcing/Offshoring, 201-500 employees,Health, Wellness and Fitness, 5001-10,000 employees |
| xyz | Jack Jones, Rick Paul, Johnny Jones | Banking, 1001-5000 employees,Construction, 51-200 employees,Consumer Goods, 10,001+ employees |
| def | Tom D., Connie J. | Unspecified, Unspecified |

output i'd like to get:

| software | name | business |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | Andrew Johnson | Outsourcing/Offshoring, 201-500 employees |
| abc | Steve Martin | Health, Wellness and Fitness, 5001-10,000 employees |
| xyz | Jack Jones | Banking, 1001-5000 employees |
| xyz | Rick Paul | Construction, 51-200 employees |
| xyz | Johnny Jones | Consumer Goods, 10,001+ employees |
| def | Tom D | Unspecified |
| def | Connie J | Unspecified |

There are additional columns similar to 'name' and 'business' that contain multiple pieces of information that need to be split up just like 'name' and 'business'. Cells that contain multiple pieces of information are in sequence (ordered).

Here's the code I have so far and creates new rows but it only splits up the contents in name column, but that leaves the business column and a few other columns left over that need to be split up along with the contents from the name column.

```
name2 = df.name.str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
df = df.join(pd.Series(index=name2.index.droplevel(1), data=name2.values, name = 'name2'))

dict = df.to_dict('record')
for row in dict:
    new_segment = {}
    new_segment['name'] = str(row['name2'])
    #df['name'] = str(row['name2'])

    for col,content in new_segment.items():
            row[col] = content

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)

df = df.drop('name2', 1)
```

Comment: The formatting for the table was coming out correct when I was typing out the question but now it appears to be out of place. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Make sure there's a newline between the markdown table and preceding text.

Comment: Maybe you can split the non `unspecified` strings in `business` column with keyword `employees` like `business_value.split('employees')`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `pandas 1.3.0` it's possible to [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas.DataFrame.explode) on multiple columns. So a simple solution would be to:

1. Split `name` on comma and `business` on commas after 'employees' or 'Unspecified' (implemented with regex below)
2. Explode on both `name` and `business`

This makes:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''software  name    business
abc Andrew Johnson, Steve Martin    Outsourcing/Offshoring, 201-500 employees,Health, Wellness and Fitness, 5001-10,000 employees
xyz Jack Jones, Rick Paul, Johnny Jones Banking, 1001-5000 employees,Construction, 51-200 employees,Consumer Goods, 10,001+ employees
def Tom D., Connie J.   Unspecified, Unspecified'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep = '\t')
df['name'] = df['name'].str.split(', ')
df['business'] = df['business'].str.split(r'(?<=employees)\,\s*|(?<=Unspecified)\,\s*')
df = df.explode(['name','business']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

result:

|  | software | name | business |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | abc | Andrew Johnson | Outsourcing/Offshoring, 201-500 employees |
| 1 | abc | Steve Martin | Health, Wellness and Fitness, 5001-10,000 employees |
| 2 | xyz | Jack Jones | Banking, 1001-5000 employees |
| 3 | xyz | Rick Paul | Construction, 51-200 employees |
| 4 | xyz | Johnny Jones | Consumer Goods, 10,001+ employees |
| 5 | def | Tom D. | Unspecified |
| 6 | def | Connie J. | Unspecified |

Comment: I get this error when running the code: 
KeyError: 'name'

Comment: Perhaps the name column is called name2 in your df? I just used the column names from your sample data.

Comment: Does io.StringIO work when you read in csv file data? The csv file I use has multiple different columns where the data in the columns is not all the same. When I enter df.head() just after the pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(review_file)) the dataframe comes up empty.

Comment: No, StringIO is just for the example to read the string. Just load the csv as you'd do normally, eg `df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep = '\t')`. Note: this assumes that the separators are tabs, like your example.

Comment: I seemed to have finally got it working but the code provided results in a business column that still contains all the same information except now the entire string is surrounded by square brackets. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Yes, you changed the code so it only explodes on `name`. The issue you mentioned is probably caused by strings in the `business` column that do not match the criteria of your sample data. My answers assumes that splits only need to occur after 'employees' or 'Unspecified'. Exceptions result in lists that are too short that throw the error you mentioned in your removed comment. Please share your full csv, I can't help you otherwise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238004/discussion-between-tahakhawaja-and-rj-adriaansen).